# Show different message after click button - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

When user click Click to avail offer! It showing the offer, but when I click same button or refresh page I have to show "You already availed the offer" message. I want to store this in cookie as per IP, I tried but its not working. I am beginner of PHP, any help highly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn">
    <button class="button" onclick="showoffers()" >Click to avail offer!</button>
</div>      
<div class="offer">     
    <div id="coupon"></div>
    <div id="nooffers"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function showoffers(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'cookies.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async:false,    
        dataType: "json",                         
        success: function(data) {

        if(data.Status==1){
            jQuery('#coupon').html('');
            jQuery('#coupon').html(data.msg);
        }else{
            jQuery('#nooffers').html('');
            jQuery('#nooffers').html(data.msg)
        }
        }
    });return false;
}
```

**PHP**

cookies.php file

```
<?php
    $rand_keys='';
    $input = array('You got 40% off on all plans');
    shuffle($input);
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);

    $now = time();
    $your_date = strtotime("2017-11-25");
    $datediff = $your_date - $now;

    $day= floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24))+1;

    $ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if (isset($_COOKIE['offers_ip']) && $_COOKIE['offers_ip']!='') {
    $vArray=array('Status'=>0,"msg"=>$_COOKIE['offers_ip']);
    echo json_encode($vArray);
    }
    else{
    $value = $input[$rand_keys];
    setcookie('offers_ip', $value, time() + (60*60*24*$day), 'offerpage.php');
    $vArray=array('Status'=>1,"msg"=>$input[$rand_keys]);
    echo json_encode($vArray);

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Recommend code formatting the cookies.php file.

Comment: @TomAranda Thanks, but how can I rewrite?

Comment: I looks good now.

Comment: do you want the offer to be availed only once per ip? or per user logged in?

Comment: @apelidoko, for all user same offer, but when user click of refresh the page, I have to show You already availed offer.

Comment: for all user same offer, 
so you mean it can only be availed once per ip address,? 

if i have 2 laptops, and then logged in with same user, i should be able to avail it twice since we are storing ip address in your cookies not usernames,

laptop1 with user1 and laptop2 with user1,

im sorry i got confused because we are displaying 'You already availed this offer' pertaining to a user

Comment: For one device I have to show it only once, It doesn't matter how many device they have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting cookie path to "/" ie

```
setcookie('offers_ip', $value, time() + (60*60*24*$day), '/');
```

As per my understanding you have set the cookie path for "offerpage.php" page and trying to access in "cookies.php" page

Comment: Thanks, Where I can add message for 'You already availed offer'.

Comment: u can send the message in json also , or u can add in ur js too